# Heroku not updating code after pushing from Heroku CLI

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

checking my source tab on devtools, I see that Heroku hasn't updated for the last 6-7 deployments (after pushing using Heroku CLI) that I've made.

I have done every suggestion on Google, including

`git push heroku your_local_branch_name:master`

`heroku builds:cache:purge -a example-app` (https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) <-- this entire thing

I'm watching the app on my Heroku deploy over and over again, but the changes haven't been implemented.

Does anyone have any idea? I can't email Heroku because I'm using the free account. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Heroku just took a long time to do the updating. I came back the next day and it had updated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When the deployment finishes, your app should be updated. Are you sure your browser didn't just have something cached? Or maybe a Redis or other application-side cache that needed to be refreshed? You haven't told us anything about your application, so we can't say for sure...